# PCA using prcomp for RNA seq in R

Tags: r, pca

I was wondering if I need to transpose the data for doing PCA on my samples in R. I'm using the built-in function prcomp(). My dataset is RNA seq expression data and the columns are samples and rows are gene expressions. It seems it works either way but is there a consensus of what should be in the rows/columns? Thanks!

Comment: Indeed it will "work either way", mathematically-speaking. However, for most data analysis, the columns contain variables of interest (genes in your case), the rows contain observations of those variables (samples in your case).

Comment: Thanks @neilfws! Just to clarify, I'm interested in seeing the relationships among the samples, using genes as the vectors. So still the genes should be in the columns?

Answer (score 0):

Most biostatistics R-packages do this by transposing the data frame. I will give you a proof:

The RUV SVD factorisation method is common in RNA-Seq. Look at it's source code:

> https://github.com/drisso/RUVSeq/blob/master/R/RUVg-methods.R

```
if(isLog) {
    Y <- t(x)
} else {
    Y <- t(log(x+epsilon))
}
```

`x` is the gene matrix table. Do you see the transpose operation? Later in the code the package gives the transposed matrix (Y) into the `svd` function.

```
svdWa <- svd(...)
```

To make life and others easier, you may want to put genes in your columns and samples in your rows.